# Dynamic images slider for PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, slider, phonegap-plugins

Is there any PhoneGap slider to slide dynamically loaded images? A few slider like SlideJS, iDangerous Slider, Jquery mobile slider function properly until the images are static but stop functioning when linked to dynamic source.

Answer (score 0):

Codesnippets would be great!

Working Imageslider i used last time was flexslider for JQM.

Comment: I've used flexslider as well but it does not work for PhoneGap as well as dynamic content. It's working fine with static images

Comment: Can you give us a codesnippet - what exactly do u mean with Dynamic Content

Comment: Dynamic content means the images are loading from web-services and not stored on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this functionality by using [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)